# Randomize Parallel Recipe Execution Order In Makefile

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-make, makefile, multiple-makefiles

I have a makefile that has a ton of subsystem and am able to build it with the -j flag so that it goes much faster and builds the different recipes in parallel.

This seems to be working fine for now but am not sure if I am missing some needed dependencies and am just "getting lucky" with the order that these are being built.

Is there a way where I can randomize the order recipes are run while still following all the dependencies that I have defined?

Comment: `GNU make` follows all dependencies strictly. It will not build something if all its dependencies are not up to date.

Comment: The only way is to do it yourself in your makefile.  Make has no ability to do this.

Comment: You could redefine `CC`, `CXX`, etc with something like: `CC:=sleep $(bc -l <<< "scale=4 ; ${RANDOM}/3276") && gcc`, which will randomize build order a bit

Comment: @igagis I am talking more about the things that dont depend on each other. For example if you have rules A-F and only B depends on C  then there could be issues when it runs A C D E F B vs running F A E D C B but when it runs ether way it follows the dependence rules.

Comment: @DanielH If there are issues if those are run in wrong order, then you have to specify dependencies so that those are run in correct order. It's a matter of writing your `makefile` properly.

Comment: @igagis I agree! I am trying to find if there are any dependencies that I am missing. It is working now but there are 60ish things being built and I am not the original archetecht. I am just changing over to use make and want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem. To find out if all targets are built properly, run a clean build. For the dependencies, IIRC, gmake has an option to dump the dependency tree. But as I use a more modern tool (SCons) which is also more reliable on rebuilds, I can be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can control number of jobs Make is allowed to run asynchronously with `-j` command line option. This way you can "randomize" recipes being executed simultaneously and catch some issues in your makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'll duplicate the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722756/5610270 here:

> Next release of `GNU make` will have `--shuffle` mode. It will allow
> you to execute prerequisites in random order to shake out missing
> dependencies by running `$ make --shuffle`.
>
> The feature was recently added in
> https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?62100 and so far is available
> only in `GNU make`'s git tree.